# using egrep to find missing @ in log

Tags: command-line, scripts, grep

I am using the following command to find log entries that are the result of a log in to the email server:

```
egrep '_login[^ ]' /var/log/exim_mainlog
```

That works fine to find entries that contain content like this:

```
P=esmtpa A=courier_login:name@email.net S=1573 id=f1cd08396,...
```

But what I need to do is to change my grep statement, so that it finds single word logins that do not use the @ sign, like so:

```
 P=esmtpa A=courier_login:name S=1573 id=f1cd08396,...
```

Where the log in before was "name@email.net", but in the second log entry, the log in used was only "name".

Is this possible using grep or egrep, perhaps in some kind of a compound statement?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

The extended regular expression `_login[^ ][^@]+\s` should do it.

That is the literal string `_login` followed by a character which is not a space, followed by at least one character which is not `@`, followed by a whitespace character.

Comment: Thanks but it does not seem to work that way. I just tried this --- egrep '_login[^ ][^@]+\s' /var/log/exim_mainlog --- and I get all the log entries with user@domain.com instead of just user.

Comment: Works for me. Try with a space instead of the `\s` - Maybe your `grep` interprets it differently.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to extract only the login names that do not contain the @ character, the following `sed` command might come handy:

```
echo -e "P=esmtpa A=courier_login:name1@email.net S=1573 id=f1cd08396,...\nP=esmtpa A=courier_login:name2 S=1573 id=f1cd08396,..." | \
sed -nr 's/^.*_login:([^ @]+) .*$/\1/p'
```

Running this script will result in the output below:

```
name2
```

Some explanation:

- The first line just echoes 2 lines of example data (separated by a newline `\n` character).
- The second line contains the `sed -nr` command, that in this case uses the `s/regexp/replacement/p` syntax. It (`s`) searches the line for a matching `regexp` regular expression (`-r`). If a portion of the line is matched, the `replacement` will be used to replace the matching portion. The `-n` switch and `p` command are only required to omit lines that are not matching the `regexp`.
- `sed` locates the string "`_login:`" in a line. At that position:

  - The opening bracket marks the start of a sub-expression. (Consider it a region of the line.)
  - The `[^ @]+` matches one more character that is neither a space nor @. It will expand until a space character is found.
  - The closing bracket marks the end of the sub-expression just before this character. The matched region is stored in a variable called `\1`.
- If you take a look at the `regexp` part it basically follows the `^.*something.*$` pattern. The `^.*` matches any characters at the beginning of the line until the expression *something*. Similarly the `.*$` matches any characters at the end of line after the expression *something*. Matching the whole line with the `regexp` is important, because the whole matched portion is replaced.
- The replacement part only contains the `\1` variable, thus the matched login name will be substituted.

Comment: Thanks but I am not interested in extracting only the names, but rather we need to know who is logging into the email services, NOT using the full user ID which includes the @ sign.

Comment: Well I believed that you look for both. Actually it only makes a one character difference, but edited the answer a bit for legibility.